# which determines the number of map tasks and reduce tasks in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I use hive to run a query "select * from T1,T2 where T1.a=T2.b", and the schema is T1(a int, b int),T2(a int,b int), when it runs, 6 map tasks and one reduce task generated, and I want to ask that, which determined the number of map tasks and reduce tasks? is the data volume?

Answer (score 0):

The number of map tasks is dependent on the data volume, block size and split size.
For example: If you have block size 128 MB and your file size is 1 GB then there will be 8 number of map tasks. You can control it by using split size.

And number of reducers in a Hive job is 1 by default. You have to update it via configuration

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
  <value>-1</value>
  <description>The default number of reduce tasks per job.  Typically set
   to a prime close to the number of available hosts.  Ignored when
   mapred.job.tracker is "local". Hadoop set this to 1 by default, whereas hive uses
  -1 as its default value.
   By setting this property to -1, Hive will automatically figure out what should be
   the number of reducers.
  </description>
</property>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but is the blocks' number determines the number of map tasks? or splits' number? I think it is the splits' number.:)

Comment: By default it is block size but you can customize it by specifying split size configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> Parameters which decides your split Size, in-turn you no of Map Tasks are.

```
> mapred.max.split.size 
> mapred.min.split.size
```

> `"mapred.max.split.size"` which can be set per job individually through
>   your conf Object. Don't change "dfs.block.size" which affects your
>   HDFS too.
>
> if `mapred.min.split.size` is less than block size and
>   `mapred.max.split.size` is greater than block size then 1 block is sent
>   to each map task. The block data  is split into key value pairs based
>   on the Input Format you use.

Answer (score 0):

**hive> select * from emp;**
Then there will be no map and reduce will start. Means we are only dumping the data.

If I want so how many map and reduce start when I am hitting query.

**hive> select count(*) from emp group by name;**

If we added **explain** keyword before the query it will going show how many **map and reduce will get start.**

**hive> explain select count(*) from emp group by name;**