# output message from Hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive

When using Hive query, here is the output during the progress of execution, want to confirm it means the query use 27 mapper and 1 reducer? Or using 27 split with 1 mapper?

```
Map 1: 21/27    Reducer 2: 0/1
Map 1: 22/27    Reducer 2: 0/1
Map 1: 23/27    Reducer 2: 0/1
Map 1: 24/27    Reducer 2: 0/1
Map 1: 26/27    Reducer 2: 0/1
Map 1: 27/27    Reducer 2: 0/1
Map 1: 27/27    Reducer 2: 1/1
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is using 27 mappers and 1 reducers. The number of mappers and reducers are decided based on the data (number of splits). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287403/which-determines-the-number-of-map-tasks-and-reduce-tasks-in-hive) for more details.